# Copying a folder using copyfolder method is not working when scheduled on windows scheduler

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a script to copy a folder from one location to another location (final destination). The final destination folder is created first and then the process of copying starts.

In the following code, `newfolder` has the path of the final destination. `objFSO.CreateFolder(newfolder)` creates the folder. And `objFSO.getfolder ("n:\Source_Folder\").copy newfolder, True` copies the entire content of the `Source_Folder` folder to `newfolder`

```
newfolder = "F:\Root\" & "Subfolder " & FormatDateTime (todaysdate,1)

objFSO.CreateFolder(newfolder)

objFSO.getfolder ("n:\Source_Folder\").copy newfolder, True
```

The script works when I double click on it. But it does not when I set it to run via the windows scheduler.

It does create the new folder but the content of Source_folder is never copied over. Any suggestions as to why this is happening.